# Barring Heat, What is the Upper Limit of overclocking

Tags: cpu, gpu, cpu-usage, overclocking, cpu-speed

Except for heat, what governs the maximum a CPU or GPU can be overclocked? Perhaps the speed of the bus?

I'm a newb.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correctness of results is the limit.

When starting to overclock, some combinatorial circuit won't complete its operations in time any more, but only with *some* operands (e.g. an adder when carrying "1" bits)... but the sequential logic systems will still use the "intermediate" result.

With moderate overclocking, usually it still *looks* as if would be working fine, but only *until* critical operands meet! Some computations will start to yield incorrect results, with arbitrary effects to your data (including corruption of data, or even total data loss).

Comment: Incorrectness of results is typically due to insufficient transition time on the transistors, and can be fixed by increasing voltage ... which increases heat faster than linearly. So... the limit here is heat. (Well, no, with sufficient cooling the true limit would be speed-of-light, but we're not quite there yet.)